# Can't find postgresql client installed using yum on cent os 7 running in docker

Tags: postgresql, docker, centos7

I have a CentOS image running in Docker. I don't have root access to this image. The only thing I can control is the dockerfile.

Anyway, I have the yum command to install postgresql in my dockerfile. From the output I can see that the yum command is succeeding.

Now when I ssh into the host, and type "psql", the console outputs with cmd not found. Most likely due to path not being set. But since I don't have root access, my hands are tied. I tried to use locate command but then again CentOS doesn't seem to have that command by default.

My question is two folds:

1. How do I locate postgresql client on a CentOS docker image that I don't have root access to? I tried the expected default paths like /usr/lib or /etc/ but no luck.
2. Is there anything I can print/echo on my dockerfile that could help me get the location of postgresql client?

Comment: It sounds like you are using docker as a VM? There are a number of perfectly fine postgres docker containers available, even from the official public repo (https://hub.docker.com/_/postgres). Why would you go through "installing" it in a container?

Comment: Fwiw: If you really insist on using docker this way, look at the configuration done on the official postgres container (as linked above) and use that dockerfile for your own benefit. That should at least get you going.

Comment: I just want to install the pg client so I can make postgres queries against RDS in AWS. Because of how VPC is setup for RDS, I can only access the db via SSHing into the host and making queries from there. Hope what I said makes sense. Very new to the docker world.

Comment: It makes sense what you said but I would not use docker for this. The purpose of the (docker) container is different. I think you'd be better of just using the small EC2 instance with CentOS installed on it and SSH from there on in.

Comment: Another thing you can do is install `psql` locally, and then use `ssh -L` tunneling to connect via the jump server to the remote database.  But this setup isn't really the sort of programming question that's on-topic for Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 0):

Try looking here:

`/var/lib/postgresql/data`

You can also specify the docker path where bd will be installed:
`volumes: - ./data/db:/var/lib/postgresql/data`.